# Conditional thread interrupt

Tags: java, concurrency, interrupt

In some code I'm working on, there are a couple of places where I do something like this:

```
public MyThread extends Thread{
    boolean finished = false;
    BlockingQueue<Foo> blockingQueue new LinkedBlockingQueue<Foo>();

    public void run(){
        while(!finished || (finished && !blockingQueue.isEmpty())){
            try{
                Foo f = blockingQueue.take();

                insertIntoDatabase(f);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){

            }
        }
    }

    public void insertThis(Foo f) throws InterruptedException{
        blockingQueue.put(f);
    }

    public void stop(){
        finished = true;
        this.interrupt();
    }
}
```

This, however, is causing problems as the thread is sometimes interrupted when it is in the `insertIntoDatabase()` method. As we're using Apache Derby, it throws a hissy fit (to wit: "java.sql.SQLException: Derby thread received an interrupt during a disk I/O operation, please check your application for the source of the interrupt."), and all subsequent database communication falls down in a nasty mess. Is there any tidy way to protect the thread from an interrupt when it's not waiting on the blocking queue, or alternatively to target the interrupt at the blocking queue?

Two solutions that I have seen suggested or have occurred to me are to insert a "poison pill" object into the queue to shut it down, and to have an extra `boolean interruptsWelcome` field that could be checked by the `stop()` method, but neither is particularly attractive to me - I'd either have to mess with the class hierarchy (`Foo` is not a trivial class) or produce masses of synchronisation code. Is there something neater?

Comment: Are you saying the Apache code *itself* does not handle thread interruptions, and you want to block interruptions while the Apache code runs? Because I'd say that was a bug in the Apache code.

Comment: I think it's a feature rather than a bug. It shows all signs of being recoverable - just the current connection is broken, but I don't want to have to open new connections when this is towards the end of the application's life cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you may want to do is to use an ExecutorService.  In which you can use a single thread to submit the foo requests.

```
    class FooRunner{

     ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

     //where RunnableFoo extends Foo and implements Runnable
        public void insertThis(RunnableFoo f) throws InterruptedException{ Run
            service.submit(f);
        }
        public void stop(){
            service.shutdown();
        }

    }
```

Your runnable itself can just ignore interrupted exception if you want

```
class RunnableFoo extends Foo implements Runnable{

 public void run(){
     try{
         insertIntoDatabase(this);
     }catch(InterruptedException ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
}
```

Edit:

I saw your comment on the other answer and to answer that question in terms of using an ExecutorService.  By having a singleThreadExeuctor you are restricting to one upload via thread-confinement.  If only one thread is running within the service only one runnable will run at a time.  The others will just queue up until the previous finished.

Comment: It rather looks like I've been caught unnecessarily re-inventing the wheel again. I thought I was being rather clever when I wrote `MyThread`. :-D Seems like `ExecutorService` is the way to go. `Foo` is already mostly `Runnable` - they used to all run as individual threads.

Comment: Yea :) dont feel bad.  A co-woker of mine tried to implement a synchronizer without the concept of conditions.  The frustration on his face when I showed him what a CountdownLatch was

Comment: its almost as good as the answer I gave 3 hours earlier, ;) except submit() doesn't throw an InterruptedException, and as the poster says, insertIntoDatabase() doesn't throw it either (it gives a different exceptions)  OP says Foo is a complex object so wrapping it is possibly better than extending it.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is not to allow thread interruption while running `insertIntoDatabase()`, factor out call to this method to separate Runnable and submit it to separate Executor:

```
    while(!finished || (finished && !blockingQueue.isEmpty())){
        try{
            final Foo f = blockingQueue.take();

            executor.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    insertIntoDatabase(f);
                }
            });
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){

        }
    }
```

Comment: How do I synchronise on the `Executor` tasks so that a) only one object is being uploaded at a time and b) when the `MyThread` stops, we know that no more database interaction will occur?

Comment: Scott: a) you can use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` to ensure sequential execution. b) from the code, when `MyThread` stops, it won't submit new tasks to executor. It can happen that last submitted task outlive `MyThread`, but it should be ok. Before return from `MyThread.run()` you can call `ExecutorService.shutdown()` to ensure last sumbitted task finished.

Answer (score 2):

You could place sentinel value to stop processing. This doesn't require an interrupt or complex checking.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{
    static final Foo STOP = new Foo();
    final BlockingQueue<Foo> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Foo>();

    public void run(){
        try{
           Foo f = queue.take();
           while(f != STOP) {
              insertIntoDatabase(f);
              f = queue.take();
           }
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void insertThis(Foo f) {
        queue.add(f); // never fills up.
    }

    public void stop() {
        queue.add(STOP);
    }
}
```

Another way might be to use an ExecutorService.

```
public class DatabaseWriter {
   final ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

   public void insertThis(final Foo f) {
       es.submit(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
              insertIntoDatabase(f);
           }
       });
   }

   public void stop() {
       es.shutdown();
   }
}
```

Comment: I understand the "poison pill" method, but it's not something I want to do. `Foo` is a fairly large class, and I'd rather not provide no-argument constructors and leave all the fields null. Maybe it's a phobia - I'm overly fond of immutable objects, too. `ExecutorService` looks like the way to go - after all, I seem to have been trying to more or less re-implement it.

Comment: Its cleaner IMHO and you can mix/match what the background thread does or the number of threads easily.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this.interrupt() then. It seems it works as intended, but the JDBC driver is turning the InterruptedException into an SQLException, thus bypassing your exception handling.

Just set the finished boolean and wait for all I/O to complete.

Comment: If I just set `finished` to true, there is the possibility that it wouldn't ever finish if the thread was blocked at `blockingQueue.take()` and the blocking queue was already empty, with no more entries likely to arrive. Hence the interrupt.

Comment: use `poll(...)` instead of `take()`. Gives you controlled finishing of the thread without interrupting important actions (like talking to the DB)

Comment: It also gives me a busy wait and a need for code to handle to case where `poll()` times out.

Comment: Looks like you can't have your cake and eat it too. If you issue interrupt and a library like the JDBC driver decides to wrap this into a different exception, you either need to handle this exception and deal with the rollback in the DB or you have to wait for some actions to finish. If you want to guarantee that an item taken from the blocking queue has been handled, you can't issue interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the `finished` variable should be enough, but only if it is `volatile`. Without volatile there's no guarantee the reading thread will ever see a write to it.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add `volatile` to the example I gave, but, as I said to Jochen, `finished` isn't enough on its own - the thread will never get to read it if it's blocked in the `blockingQueue.take()` method because the `BlockingQueue` is empty.

Comment: true that, you should then probably just take with a timeout and periodically check fishished