# Object without a value

Tags: java, object

I was asking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737870/conditional-thread-interrupt) question about controlling a thread that was reading from a blocking queue. Although it wasn't the solution I chose to go with, several people suggested that a special "poison pill" or "sentinel" value be added to the queue to shut it down like so:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{
    private static final Foo STOP = new Foo();
    private BlockingQueue<Foo> blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Foo>();

    public void run(){
        try{
            Foo f = blockingQueue.take();
            while(f != STOP){
                doSomethingWith(f);
                f = blockingQueue.take();
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){

        }
    }

    public void addToQueue(Foo f) throws InterruptedException{
        blockingQueue.put(f);
    }

    public void stop() throws InterruptedException{
        blockingQueue.put(STOP);
    }
}
```

While I like this approach, I decided not to use it because I wasn't sure what value to use for the `STOP` field. In some situations it's obvious - for instance, if you know you're inserting positive integers, negative numbers could be used as control values - but `Foo` is a fairly complex class. It's immutable and hence has a constructor that takes several arguments. To add a no-argument constructor would mean leaving several fields uninitialised or null, which would cause methods to break if they were used elsewhere - `Foo` is not just used with `MyThread`. Similarly, putting dummy values into the main constructor would just pass this problem on as several of the fields and constructor parameters are themselves significant objects.

Am I simply programming over-defensively? Should I worry about adding no-argument constructors to a class, even if there are no setters to make the object usable (just assume other programmers will be sensible enough to not use that constructor)? Is the design of `Foo` broken if it can't have a no-argument constructor or at least a non-value - would it be better to put `if(someField == null){throw new RuntimeException();}` checks in all methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right about not using empty constructors. If Foo is such an complex class, it doesn't seem logical to use a complete object for that.

If adding a `null` is possible. That seems a nice way to go.

Another way could also be to implement an interface. `IBlockableQueueObject`? This could be implemented by the `foo` object and by the STOP sign. Only thing is that you have to cast the interface back to the `Foo` if it is not a STOP.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see what the advantage of this design is versus a simple boolean variable to indicate the loop should stop.

But if you really want to go with this design, I would suggest making a private no-arg constructor, and making a static STOP Foo.  Like this.

```
public class Foo {

  public static final Foo STOP = new Foo();
  ... fields

  private Foo(){}
  public Foo(...){
    ...
  }

  ...

}

public class MyThread extends Thread{
  private static final Foo STOP = new Foo();
  private BlockingQueue<Foo> blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Foo>();

  public void run(){
      try{
          Foo f = blockingQueue.take();
          while(f != STOP){
              doSomethingWith(f);
              f = blockingQueue.take();
          }
      }
      catch(InterruptedException e){

      }
  }

  public void addToQueue(Foo f) throws InterruptedException{
      blockingQueue.put(f);
  }

  public void stop() throws InterruptedException{
      blockingQueue.put(Foo.STOP);
  }
}
```

This has the advantage that you're still not exposing an invalid constructor.

The disadvantage is that the `Foo` class knows that in some cases it's used as a 'poison pill', which might not be what it's for.  Another disadvantage is that The `STOP` object might be inconsistent.  You could make an anonymous subclass from it do disable the methods with UnsupportedOperationException or something.

Answer (score 1):

another option would be to wrap Foo in a generic wrapper such as this:

```
public class Wrapped<T> {
    private final T value;

    public Wrapped(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T get() { return value; }
}
```

which you can then use to pass a null value as a poison pill to a `BlockingQueue<Wrapped<Foo>>`.

Answer (score 0):

You *should* worry about having no-argument constructors that don't result in usable instances.

The design of Foo sounds fine - I would generally assume that I'm not allowed to pass in null into a constructor unless the documentation specifically allows me to. Especially with an immutable class.